# Рег. Замена пробела между двух выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение, которое бы заменяло пробел на подчеркивание между двух выражений.
На входе некоторый текст, в нем адрес, в котором есть почтовый код и город:

> текст адреса **1111-222 City** дальше текст

1111 и 222 - числа длиной от 2 до 5 символов, между ними дефис,
далее идет пробел, за ним слово (город).

Рег. выражение должно вернуть:

> текст адреса **1111-222_City** дальше текст

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

видимо что-то вроде такого

```
preg_replace('/(\d{2,5}-\d{2,5})\s+/', "$1_", $str);
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление, но пока кидает ошибку "preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Comment: @mico изменил порядок аргументво

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]